# Maven 3.3.9 with JDK 1.8 threw: DependencyGraphBuilderException

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, aerogear

I am trying to build a Maven project Aerogear UPS Version 1.1.0-Final, and got the following error:

```
A required class was missing while executing com.qmino:miredot-plugin:1.6.1:restdoc: 
org/apache/maven/shared/dependency/graph/DependencyGraphBuilderException
```

I know it has nothing to do with the code inside the project, most probably related to Maven. I appreciate your device how to fix this error.

*** UPDATE:
I am pretty sure this is not code problem as I am trying to build a released version from here: https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-server/tree/1.1.0.Final

Comment: You have a dependency that's missing a required class.  If it's one of your dependencies, find and add it to your pom.xml.  If it's required by a Maven plug in, remove it and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am pretty sure this is not code problem as I am trying to build a released version from here: https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-server/tree/1.1.0.Final

Comment: Looks like a problem with the plugin you are using (miredot-plugin?) I would take a look if there is newer version of the plugin available?

Comment: Would you mind adding a pastebin/github gist link to the output of your command (for bonus points you can also add -X) ?  I've checked out the project and it builds fine.